# How to mount Angular components in Cypress?

Tags: angular, typescript, cypress

I am trying to test individual components for my Angular project following the guidelines set up in the official Cypress [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/component-testing/testing-angular#Selecting-the-StepperComponent).

I have created the following `cy.ts` file for one of my components

```
import {SpInputComponent} from "[abriged]/sp-input.component";

describe('Sp-Input component', () => {
  it('mounts', () => {
    cy.mount('<app-sp-input></app-sp-input>', {
      declarations: [SpInputComponent]
    })
  })
})
```

Unfortunately, when I try to run the test in Cypress, I get the following `NullInjectionError`.
[image]

The component in question uses a service that is dependent on `HttpClient` (i.e. uses `HttpClient` in its constructor). I tried importing the `HttpClient` module as well as the service that uses it into the test file without success.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: when you say "you tried to import it" what does this mean? Please post code of what you tried and didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the answers but I discovered what the problem was. I had to add the providers 'attribute', as you rightfully pointed out, and added the services that were mentioned in the error message. In my case it was my custom `ToolboxRepositoryService`, the `HttpClient` and `HttpHandler` from angular's http module.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the http client module import, MountConfig is an extension from Angular TestModuleMetadata. So you just need to add the import like the example below.

```
describe('Sp-Input component', () => {
  it('mounts', () => {
    cy.mount('<app-sp-input></app-sp-input>', {
      declarations: [SpInputComponent],
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule] // <-- you need this
    })
  })
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a guess since you haven't posted your component under test but:

```
import {SpInputComponent} from "[abriged]/sp-input.component";
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';

describe('Sp-Input component', () => {
  it('mounts', () => {
    cy.mount('<app-sp-input></app-sp-input>', {
      declarations: [SpInputComponent],
      providers: [HttpClientTestingModule]
    })
  })
})
```